# dotnet build process always outputting createdump.exe in bin path

Tags: .net, nuget-package

Is there a way to run `dotnet pack` (or any build) without producing `createdump.exe` in the bin / output folder?

```
dotnet pack -c Release /p:NuspecFile=.\mynugetpackage.nuspec
```

I've also tried splitting into two commads - a `dotnet build` followed by manual removal of `createdump.exe` followed by `dotnetpack --no-build` but it still doesn't work - the resultant nuget package always includes `createdump.exe`.

Is there a way to prevent `createdump.exe` ever being included in the build output?

.net6.0 project, but was a problem eith net5.0 and netcore3.x.